# Importing java packages into Android

Tags: java, android, normalization

Actually I am working on an Android App which utilizes the normalization package of Java. This packages has been ported into Android SDK from the version 2.3 (API 9).
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html

The problem is that I want to my application to reach as much people as possible, and it seems that android 2.2 is still very popular.
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

My question is, is there any way to import the Normalize package from Java using Android 2.2 (API 8)?

Comment: You could use the source code and just implement it yourself http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/Normalizer.java

Comment: @dymmeh is right, it often happens that you have to include some parts of a future version of the API of android into a project just to remain backward compatible with a previous version of android that doesn't include this class.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the source code for it, refactor it into some other package (you will not be able to reliably have `java.text` classes in your app), and give it a whirl. Please adhere to all relevant licensing terms -- for example, the linked-to OpenJDK is licensed under the GPL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do it.